# PHP For each Loop returns one value

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I am having a small confusion here, i am creating a calender using a laravel plugin by Crinsane, the only problem is displaying multiple dates from my values delivered from the database using foreach loop. The basic structure is this

```
$data = array(
    3  => 'http://example.com/news/article/2006/03/',
    7  => 'http://example.com/news/article/2006/07/',
);

Calendar::generate(2006, 6, $data);
```

This will render a calender. But my data values are from database. This is my foreach loop

```
   @foreach ($events as $a)
       <?php  $string = $a->datebooked;
       $date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d" ,$string);
       $date=$date->format("d");
       $date;?>
       <?php $data=array(
           $date=> $a->eventname,
         )?>
   @endforeach

 <?php echo Calendar::generate(date('Y'), date('n'), $data); ?>
```

When i run this code, it only displays the last event date, i know it is because it loops through the whole data variable, but how can i make it loop through $date=> $a->eventname only ?

Comment: It seem that your `$data` array is getting overwritten each time in your loop.

Comment: Thanks 4 helping, yeah i know that, how do i prevent it from being overwritten , that was my question...

Comment: I want an output like this    $data = array(
    3  => 'event 1',
    7  => 'event 2',
);  But so far only event 2 is showing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside of the for-each loop, you don't want to overwrite $data, but add to it. The quick and dirty way to do this is to define a $data array outside the foreach-loop, then append to the array like such

```
<?php
$data = array();
?>
@foreach ($events as $a)
   <?php

   $string = $a->datebooked;
   $date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $string);
   $date = $date->format("d");
   $data[] = array($date => $a->eventname);
   ?>
@endforeach
```

This isn't a great way to mix PHP into your view, though; as a suggestion, I'd put the logic to create $data into your controller, and only call Calendar::generate in the view.

Comment: Thanks @chris for helping :-) I made some changes in your code because i was getting some syntax errors, i change $data=[] to $data[]="" and $data[] = [$date => $a->eventname]; to $data=array($date => $a->eventname); , when i run it , still i get the last value from my events table and yes , i agree with you on view controller mixing, wil change that, thanks again 4 helpng me out and pliz c if u can find the way to solve this, when i print out inside the loop it returns all values but outside only the last value

Comment: @bobin56 - Well you _did_ change my main change back to what you had, the `$data[]` ;) I had thought you were using Laravel 4.2 and PHP 5.4, so I had used short-hand array syntax. I just edited my post with using the long-form array syntax ([`array()` instead of `[]`](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php))